# How to use browser Incognito Mode in visual studio when Run a web project

Tags: browser, visual-studio-2015, incognito-mode

[image]

If i Run the project, it will launch using **Google Chrome normal mode**. 
But how can i launch it using **Google Chrome Incognito Mode ?**

Comment: Any Idea how to do this in 2017?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It is very simple using **visual studio 2015 / 2017 / 2019**. You just need to add `--incognito` as command line switch and name the browser something like **Google Chrome - Incognito**.

That you can do using **Browse With..** option in visual Studio. 
**Step-1:**
[image]

**Step-2:**
[image]


***Note:*** You can do the same thing with **Firefox** and **Internet Explorer**. Here I'm adding **Internet Explorer with the -private** option.

[image]

For
Google Chrome : `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito`
Firefox : `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -private-window`
Internet Explorer/Microsoft Edge : `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -private`

Comment: For Firefox only use -private

Answer (score 21):

**For Visual Studio 2017**

1. Select button that usually says IIS Express
2. Click the down arrow
3. Select `Browse With...`

[image]

4. Click `Add...`

[image]

5. Next to `Program` write the path to Google Chrome, eg. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`
6. Next to `Arguments` write `--incognito`
7. Next to `Friendly name` write `Google Chrome (Incognito)` (or whatever suits your needs)

[image]

8. Click `OK`
9. Select your friendly name from before (eg. `Google Chrome (Incognito)`) and click `Set as Default`

[image]

Now when you click the play button next to IIS Express, Google Chrome starts in Incognito mode.

Answer (score 12):

Not the answer, but in case someone stumbles upon this question, looking for the Visual Studio Code solution, this worked for me:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Chrome: localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/app"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--incognito"
            ],
            "name": "Incog Chrome: localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/app"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this does not currently work using the Firefox debugging extension with the `-private-window` argument. Hope it helps.